# Does an analytical solution for this ODE system exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations, and I want to know if it is possible to get an analytical solution before resorting to numerical methods and software.

\begin{align}
\frac{dy_1}{dx} + y_1 - y_3 &= 0 \\
\frac{dy_2}{dx} + y_2 - y_4 &= 0 \\
\frac{dy_3}{dx} + y_1 - y_3 &= f(x)\frac{y_3}{y_3 +1}\frac{y_4}{y_4 +1} \\
\frac{dy_4}{dx} + y_2 - y_4 &= f(x)\frac{y_3}{y_3 +1}\frac{y_4}{y_4 +1} 
\end{align}

where $f(x)$ is a simple, probably linear, function

I think because of the non linear term, a solution by the laplace or eigenvalue methods is ruled out. Is there something I'm missing, or is it really only possible numerically?

Comment: It's kinda cheating, but you could choose $f(x)=(y_3+1)(y_4+1)/y_3$ to remove your non-linearity. Obviously, you don't know what that would be, yet, but it would sure simplify your system. Only problem is you might get only the trivial solution, since your system is homogeneous.

Comment: I got this system

$$z'-z+v=0$$
$$v'+v-z=0$$

Where $z=y_3-y_4$ and $v=y_1-y_2$

Comment: @Isham: What did you pick for $f(x)?$

Comment: Subtract equation $(2)$ from $(1)$ and $(4)$ from $(3)$ and you get the system given in the comment above. Thus you can solve exactly for $z = y_3 - y_4 = - c x + d(1+x)$ and $v = y_1-y_2 = c(1-x) + d x$ independent of what $f(x)$ is.

Comment: AdrianKeister I didnt take any value for f(x) because of the substraction as @winther explained...

Comment: @AdrianKeister what's interesting is, the original OP never said $f(x)$ can be freely chosen. Someone else came and edited that in, for some reason.

Comment: @Dylan: Yeah, that is interesting! That edit ought never to have been allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substract equation 2 and 1, then substract 3 and 4.

You find this system
$$
\begin{cases}
z'-z+v=0 \\
v'+v-z=0
\end{cases}
$$

Where $z=y_3-y_4$ and $v=y_1-y_2$
$$
\begin{cases}
v''=0 \implies v=k_1x+k_2-k_1 \implies y_1=y_2+k_1x+k_2-k_1 \\
z'' =0\implies z=k_1x+k_2 \implies y_3=y_4+k_1x+k_2 
\end{cases}
$$
With theses results you can solve your system ( take the first two equations).....
$$
\begin{cases}
dy_1/dx + y_1 - y_3 = 0 \\
dy_2/dx + y_2 - y_4 = 0
\end{cases}
$$